# What is Ramban's reasoning regarding charging interest to a non-Jew?

Tags: gentiles, lending-interest-ribbis, ramban, sefer-hachinuch

Sefer Hachinuch [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.573.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that Ramban holds that when the Torah says you should charge interest to a non-Jew, it means that you can, not that you must. However, we already know that we can charge a non-Jew interest. So what is Ramban's reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

Read on: Ramban says that if someone charges interest of a Jew, they have not just violated the "don't-do" of *don't charge a Jew interest*, they have also violated the "yes-do" of *instead, you may charge the non-Jew.* Just a way of strengthening the prohibition.